# how to implement button with flashlight blinking code in android studio

Tags: android, flashlight

i want to add flashlight Blinking mode in android studio with a button. but i don't know that how can i put a code and how to implement this code with a button. because i want that if i press button then flashlight start blinking.

can anyone tell me that how can i implement this code with a button?

```
String[] list1 = { "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0", "1", "0" };
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
        if (list1[i].equals("0")) {
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        } else {
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for blink i make this as method :

```
private void BlinkFlash(){
        String myString = "010101010101";
        long blinkDelay =50; //Delay in ms
        for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
            if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.startPreview();
                isFlashOn = true;



            } else {
                params = camera.getParameters();
                params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                camera.setParameters(params);
                camera.stopPreview();
                isFlashOn = false;

            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

and it will call like this :

```
BlinkMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            BlinkFlash();
        }
    });
```

Hope this will work for you and yeah make string long if you want blink long time then

Comment: yes you can do it but Thread.sleep will freee the ui and then how can we stop flash bliking agian???by clicking the button etc

Answer (score 0):

All of these below codes put inside any where in your activity/fragment:
Status, handler, Camera variables:

```
        boolean isOn[] = {false};              
        boolean[] isBlinking = {false};
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        CameraManager camManager = null;
        String cameraId = null;
```

Handle button click listener on your activity/fragment:

```
 camManager = (CameraManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

 buttonFlash.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isBlinking[0]){
                BlinkMode(view);
                isBlinking[0] = true; 
            } else {
                if(splashThread2 != null){
                    splashThread2.interrupt(); // stop blinking
                    OffFlash();
                }
                isBlinking[0] = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Blinking method:

```
    Thread splashThread2;
    private void BlinkMode(View view){
        splashThread2 = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!isInterrupted()) {
                        Thread.sleep(100);

                        if(!isOn[0]){
                            OnFlash();
                            isOn[0] = true;
                        } else {
                            isOn[0] = false;
                            OffFlash();
                        }

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        splashThread2.start();
    }
```

Handle when goback

```
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(splashThread2 != null){
            splashThread2.interrupt();   // stop blinking
            OffFlash();
        }
        // todo check null exception
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if(splashThread2 != null){
            splashThread2.interrupt();  // stop blinking
            OffFlash();
        }
        // todo check null exception
    }
```

On/Off Method for new version of Android:

```
    private void OnFlash(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);   //Turn ON
                isOn[0] = true;
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OffFlash(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);   //Turn ON
                isOn[0] = false;
            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```