# Android flashlight app using camera api 2

Tags: java, android

How can blink my flashlight app using 1 image button and using camera api 2 ?? Please someone help me.

Comment: Your question may be blocked soon. As  a word of advice, try searching the internet for code samples and if you have problems understanding, then you can ask for help here

Comment: I'm new to the development sir.so if u help me that would be great lesson for me.I could not get any answer about blinking my answer in the internet..

Comment: Hello sir how can I learn coding by myself then I won't  ask u ..if u think I have disturbed u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/04/android-developing-flashlight-application/) to learn about making flashlight android app.

To make the flashlight blink you can set up your own logic to turn it on and off programmatically.

Edit posting code as asked:

For this you should do like :

1. Check whether flash light is available or not ?
2. If yes then Turn Off/On
3. If no then you can do whatever according to your app. needs

For **Checking availability of flash** in device:

You can use the following

```
context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
```

which will return true if a flash is available, false if not.

Taking code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37505166/how-to-implement-button-with-flashlight-blinking-code-in-android-studio):

```
private void BlinkFlash(){
    String myString = "010101010101";
    long blinkDelay =50; //Delay in ms
    for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++) {
        if (myString.charAt(i) == '0') {
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;



        } else {
            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;

        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(blinkDelay);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To call this method:

```
yourbuttonname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        BlinkFlash();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have made an flashlight app using camera API 2 but I want to blink my flashlight with a Image button and and Camera API 2 since Camera ApI is deprecated. How can I blink it..please ..help me I'm so frustrated ,I don't know what to do.!!

Comment: Show your code in the question, we can help from there

Comment: Blinking a flashlight is nothing but turning the flashlight off and on continuously. Follow the tutorial given above and you will learn more about it. For the blinking, you can apply your own logic and set the params in it to turn it off and on again at a regular interval of time.

Comment: But as a new to this programming I don't know how to write code by myself ..so that's why I'm facing problems.kindly help me to blink my flashlight ..by some code useing  camera API 2

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: I have used that code but android studio saying me that camera ApI is deprecated.. So what can I do now using camera API 2

Comment: Please reach out to me at nimishnandwana@gmail.com, we can discuss and solve your problem there.

Comment: Yes sir thanks to u

Comment: Thanks  to u sir

Comment: Sir where I can learn code by myself that would be good  for me

Comment: Sir ,nimi0112 how can I talk to u  .. I need your help

Comment: That's what I am saying mail me at nimishnandwana@gmail.com, we can continue this discussion further.

Comment: Sir I have send u a mail please see that